# Invalid type code: 30 java in ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, serialization

Hi guys when I try

```
If(in.readObject() instanceof String[])a = (String[]) in.readObject;
```

Where 'in' is an objectinputstream I get an 'invalid type code: 30';

But without the if statement

```
   a = (String[]) in.readObject;
```

I get no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object input stream can contain more than one object. Each time you call `readObject()` it reads in the current object - and then moves forward. This means calling `readObject()` again will try and read the next object.

Thus, in your code above you're reading two objects - not the same one twice.

To ensure you are only reading the first object, try this:

```
Object obj = in.readObject();
if (obj instanceof String[]) {
    a = (String[]) obj;
}
```

Note we only call `readObject()` once, and then check the value of its result stored in the `obj` variable. Casting it as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

you should do it like this:

```
Object o = in.readObject();
if (o instanceof String[]) {
    a = (String[]) o;
}
```